# I want to delete specific index of list in the dataframe column

Tags: python

Dataframe contains a column named disease which include many list row by row and for example 1st row contains ['uml564','hypertensive disease'] and so on another rows have such lists now i wabt to remove theses first index of list from entire dataframe

Comment: please provide code examples you have tried and what didnt work for you. please also provide some sample that can be used (minimal reproducible code)

Answer (score 1):

********Syntax:
let us consider one example-*****

```
import pandas as pd

students = [ ('jack', 34, 'Sydeny' ,['abc', 'def','pk']) ,
             ('Riti', 30, 'Delhi' , ['India','kk']) ,
             ('Vikas', 31, 'Mumbai' , ['India','sk','uu'] ) ,
             ('Neelu', 32, 'Bangalore' ,[ 'India','kk','ok'] ) ,
             ('John', 16, 'New York' , ['US','jj']),
             ('Mike', 17, 'las vegas' , ['US','ii'])  ]


#Create a DataFrame object
dfObj = pd.DataFrame(students, columns = ['Name' , 'Age', 'City' , 'Country'],
                     index=['a', 'b', 'c' , 'd' , 'e' , 'f'])

print(dfObj)

df=dfObj['Country'].apply(lambda x: x[1:])

dfObj1= dfObj.drop(['Country'], axis=1)

df_row_merged = pd.concat([dfObj1, df],  axis=1)
```

Comment: Please format the code and data, select it and type `ctrl-k`. [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [more Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can do:

```
df['your_column_name'].apply(lambda x: x[1])
```

and if that works:

```
df['your_column_name'] = df['your_column_name'].apply(lambda x: x[1])
```

if you have a more advanced case, mixed lists and items without lists:

```
df['your_column_name'].apply(lambda x: x[1] if x== type(list) else x)
```